# How many $(x, y)$-paths of length $20$ are there, where $x$, $y$ adjacent vertices in cycle $C_5$?

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

As the title of the question suggests, let $x$ and $y$ be two adjacent vertices in the cycle $C_5$. How many $(x, y)$-paths of length $20$ are there?

Comment: A couple of clarifying questions: Is the graph only a $C_{5}$, or is there more to it? Do you mean a [walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#W) rather than a path?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual problems but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: @LukeMathieson "the cycle $C_5$" rather than "a 5-cycle" seems to be pretty unambiguous that the cycle is the whole graph. Agreed that it should be "walks" to avoid the answer being trivially zero.

Comment: @LukeMathieson Some of the literature uses "paths" and "simple paths" to refer to "walks" and "trails", respectively.  So the question is on walks (which means the same as paths).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider powers of adjacency matrix of $C_5$ ([Wiki: Matrix powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, then the $(i,j)$th entry of $A^k$ is the number of paths of length $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. This fact can be proved by induction.  So we need to obtain the $(1,2)$th entry of the matrix $A^{20}$. You can compute $A^{20}$ using a computer, or by hand by diagonalizing $A$ (observe that $A$ is a circulant matrix).  A SAGE simulation (see below) gives  the answer to be 204,820.

```
sage: c5=graphs.CycleGraph(5)
sage: A = c5.adjacency_matrix()
sage: A^20
[215766 204820 211585 211585 204820]
[204820 215766 204820 211585 211585]
[211585 204820 215766 204820 211585]
[211585 211585 204820 215766 204820]
[204820 211585 211585 204820 215766]
sage:
```